# configuring aws cloudwatch repeating alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have configured an alarm to trigger whenever bucket acl  change operation accours this works fine but the alarm is not triggering again and again.

This is what i did

1. i configured cloud watch alarm to send a email when acl of any bucket is changed my threshold is >=1
2. i changed the bucket acl of one bucket `b1`.
3. The alarms state has been changed from insufficient_state to alarm and the sns notification was triggered i recieved an email about bucket `b1`
4. after 20 minutes i changed the acl of another bucket `b2` but now the alarm is not being triggered and no sns notification hasn't occured regarding bucket `b2`

my expectation is it should trigger alarm for every change i.e for `b2` as well
I think i have configured something wrong please guide me in a correct way

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your configuration for the cloudwatch alarm please?

Comment: its a simple alarm when sum of the events in the range of 5 minutes is >=1 then trigger an alarm(static threshold type)

Comment: Could you provide the metric you're using? Is this metric growing with each ACL change or going back to zero? Is the alarm flapping between insufficient data and alarm?

Comment: yes the metric is growing but  alarm isn't flapping between insufficient data and alarm

Comment: Could you add your alarm configuration to the question?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail.html#cloudwatch-alarms-for-cloudtrail-s3-bucket-activity followed this

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to give a good reply without the full alarm and metrics setup, but I would suggest you look at two things:

1. use the FILL(m1, 0) function to use value of zero when your ACL metric m1 is "insufficient data"; that should give a more predictable data series
2. Look at the RATE() function to see if you can detect transitions of your metric.

A construct I use is FILL(PERIOD(m1)*RATE(m1), 0) which should give a blip of 1 (or -1 ...) when things change; you might need an ABS around that if the negative change is important.

You can test things out using the console Metrics view ("View in metrics"), put your expression into a new metric and see what the graphs show !